# How to remove leading underscores and numbers in a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to sanitize some strings and remove invalid leading (non-alphabet) characters from them. For example:
`"3_hello" -> "hello"
 "_hello" -> "hello"
 "__hello" -> "hello"
 "++hello" -> "hello"`

Is there a quick way to use re to compete the task?

Comment: do you know something about the word you want to obtain ?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: You can use `yourstring.lstrip('3_+')` instead here.

Comment: no, the input comes from users and I need to convert them to names starting with alphabets so that they can be processed in the system.

Comment: "remove invalid leading characters": what is an invalid character?

Comment: the sanitized string must starts with alphabets.

Comment: `(?P<remove>[\d_+]+)(?P<save>.*)`

Comment: @user2744486 It only has to start with alphabets? So, H487484(*$*___ is valid? Or does the *entire* string have to contain alphabets only?

Comment: `(?P<remove>[^a-zA-Z]*)(?P<save>.*)` the sanitized string must starts with alphabets.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: this is slightly different, OP only wants to strip leading non-alphabet chars. If we do the iterative approach (which is overkill, but anyway), need to stop when encounter first alphabet char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `^[^A-Za-z]*`, some testing cases here:

```
import re
re.sub('^[^A-Za-z]*', '', "3_hello")
# 'hello'

re.sub('^[^A-Za-z]*', '', "_hello")
# 'hello'

re.sub('^[^A-Za-z]*', '', "++hello")
# 'hello'

re.sub('^[^A-Za-z]*', '', "__hello")
# 'hello'
```

- Where the first `^` denotes the beginning of the string;
- In the character class `[]` use another `^` to negate the alpha letters;
- Use `*` as a greedy quantifier so that any non alphabets starting from the beginning of the string will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function str.isalpha() and iterate the string to get only the alphabets and place it in another variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
for string in [ "++hello", "__hello", "3_hello"]:
    print "".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]", string))

hello
hello
hello
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `re.search` to search for alphabetical string:

```
m = re.search("[a-zA-Z]+", "3_hello")
print(m.group(0))

hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and str.isalpha to strip the leading non-alphabetic characters

```
a = '3_hello'
for i in range (0, len(a)):
    if str.isalpha(a[i:]):
        a=a[i:]
        break
print(a)
```

hello